# Detect mobile device and hide iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple app where I have an iframe with html5 video and form when a user access my app it plays a video automatically.

Problem:

in my small devices, I want when the video finishes playing, automatically iframe with video should be removed from the dom (something like display: none).

Here is my solution

[Detect and hide demo plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/mjCxW2g0k5jHRfUT?preview)

Index.html

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="row expanded collapse">
                <div class="video large-8 columns large-push-4">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="400px"  id="videoframe" src="videoframe.html" autoplay>   
                      </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="columns large-4 main large-pull-8">
                    <div class="top-header">
                        <span class="logo"><img class="svg" src="img/logo-white.svg" alt=""></span>
                        <h1>Its too cold<span></span></h1>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form">
                        <span class="form-title">What is your name?</span>
                        <div class="centered">
                            <input name="client_name" id="client_name" type="text" placeholder="name" class="medium small-12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

videoframe.js

```
    var welcomeMovie1 = "http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc.mp4";
    var welcomeMovie2 = "http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/TRA3106.mp4"
    var welcomeMovie3 = "http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i.mp4";

    var messageTime = new Date().getHours();
    var welcomeMsg = "";
    var vid = " ";

    //console.log(messageTime);
    if (messageTime >= 5 && messageTime <= 10) {
      welcomeMsg = "early bird";
      vid = welcomeMovie1;
      //console.log(welcomeMessage2);
    }
    else
    if (messageTime >= 10 && messageTime < 22) {
      welcomeMsg = "middle of day";
      vid = welcomeMovie2;
      //console.log(welcomeMessage2());
    }
    else
    if (messageTime >= 22 || messageTime < 5) {
      welcomeMsg = "night owl";
      vid = welcomeMovie3;
    }
    ////}, 1000 * 60);
    playVideo(vid);

    console.log("Hello! Your welcome message is " + welcomeMsg + " " + vid)
    // promise functionb to create custom video controls and play functions
    function playVideo(src) {
      console.log("Hello! Your welcome message is " + welcomeMsg + " " + vid)
      $("#playervideo").attr("src", src);
      $("#playervideo")[0].muted = false;

      if (autoplay == true) {

        var playPromise = $("#playervideo")[0].play();

        if (playPromise !== undefined) {

          playPromise.then(function() {}).catch(function() {

            if (autoplay == true) {
              $("#video-unmute-button").addClass("show");
              $("#playervideo")[0].muted = true;
              var playPromise2 = $("#playervideo")[0].play();

              playPromise2.then(function() {

              }).catch(function() {
                $("#video-start-button").addClass("show");


                $("#video-start-button").on("click", function() {
                  $("#playervideo")[0].muted = false;
                  $("#playervideo")[0].play();
                  $("#video-start-button").removeClass("show");

                });
              });

              console.log("pause force");
            } else {

            }
          });
        } else {}
      } else {

      }

    }

    // detetct mobile device using mobile detect js 

    var detector = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent)
  document.getElementById('#playerVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
        function myHandler(e) {
         if(detector.mobile == true){
          document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').style.display = 'none';
         }
        }
```

Here is videoframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wideo iframe</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="videowrapper">
        <video  id="playervideo" playsinline controls autoplay height="500px"></video>
        <!-- <canvas id="videocanvas" width="1024" height="576"></canvas> -->
        <div class="fader"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="lib/videoframe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobile-detect/1.4.3/mobile-detect.js"></script>

</html>
```

unfortunately, my detection and hide method is not working as expected

What am I doing wrong with my codes??? thanks any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigator object to detect the device:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 $('#iframe-id').hide()
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tested it, what device are you using for testing? Maybe this link will help - https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent

Answer (score 0):

So i add detect to your code, now it will clouse iframe when your page will be open on mobile like sony, iPhone etc...
I wont make a job for you, you will have to figure, how to detect when video will finish :D 
GL xD

script i add:

```
$(function(){
  var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
if(md.phone()){
  $("#video").hide();
}
})
```

if you need to add tablet. just do it like that:

```
 if(md.phone() || md.tablet()){
      $("#video").hide();
    }
```

and that is.. if user will use tablet or phone video will hide xD you don't need to specify every model of phone :D just put thouse simple lines xD

If you need to play video 1st.. and catch when finish (without API connection for serwer side)

```
// id of video
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

// when video ends catch it and close iframe
$(function(){
  var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
  if(vid.ended && md.phone()){
    $("#video").hide();
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for help here i have tested your method with or without when video finish https://next.plnkr.co/edit/mjCxW2g0k5jHRfUT

Comment: my code working when mobile is detected. you will have to write a code to catch when video finish and after that use my function to detect mobile devices.

Comment: I dont know what kind of api you are going to use, meaning when your video will be placed YouTube? vimeo? server side?

Comment: the video will be just a link from our server example  /videos/movie1.mp4

Comment: okay I will test if will work I will accept it a soon as possible , dziekuje :)

Comment: nie ma sprawy xD powodzenia w projekcie xD jak by co promotorstron@gmail.com  jak bede miał czas to pomoge ;p

Answer (score 0):

I think the most robust/future proof way to do it is the

```
//you can adjust the width to fine tune it to current devices
if(window.screen.width < 600){
   $("#video").hide();
}
```

This way if they are using a device you didn't think of or using some kind of extension that masks their useragent, it will still behave as expected

Comment: I have added  function to detect if the video is ended playing like this ` detetct mobile device using mobile detect js 

  I have tried your method  like this here https://next.plnkr.co/edit/mjCxW2g0k5jHRfUT?previewbbut not working, any suggestion?

Comment: I mean, how wide is the screen on your test device?  You can just call window.screen.width in the console to find out

Comment: I tried the link you added, but the video never plays and the handler that should close the video is never called.